# How to Update ionic2/3 app for android/ios with out using Playstore/AppStore

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

HI here i am facing some issue related to Ionic app updates .Presently i am building the app in both android and iOS using ionic 2/3 .Presently i am distributing the app via ad-Hoc process for both Android & iOS. Below are the main issues i am facing

1. When ever i want to update the app again i am sending the app and the customer needs to uninstall the previous app and install the new app for both android & ios. Is there any way to update my app with out publishing it on playstore or app store.

Comment: You can just send the app and they can install it using the apk or ipa file. I am not sure about the ios app, but if the apk is of the same name as last it will automatically rewrite the new app over the old app

Comment: Hello, are you increasing version number, android-versionCode and ios-CFBundleVersion in config.xml?, It should work as Kevin RED says.

Answer (score 1):

There are services like Ionic Deploy that allow to update the app content.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/deploy/

Also, there are multiple plugins that allow hot code update (in example https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push, https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push)

You can also host your own code in your server and point the app to it, but it's hard to make it work as you have to serve a different cordova.js file per platform.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this pluggin App Update**
 https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/app-update/